# Hibernate 5.2.2Final JAR - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when running JAR in Hadoop

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator, nosuchmethoderror

I just updated my POM to use Hibernate Validator 5.2.2Final.  We were using 4.2.0Final version before.  I had to make a code change as below for 5.2.2Final version (as also found here - http://in.relation.to/2015/09/29/hibernate-validator-522-released/):

```
HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure();
ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = new ConstraintMapping;
```

Changed to:

```
HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure();
ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();
```

I have checked all the Referenced Libraries and Maven Dependencies and I only see 5.2.2Final.jar file in Maven. I do not see any reference to 4.2.0Final version. When I run our job in Hadoop using this JAR, I get this error:

**2016-02-12 10:18:15,285 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidatorConfiguration.createConstraintMapping()Lorg/hibernate/validator/cfg/ConstraintMapping;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidatorConfiguration.createConstraintMapping()Lorg/hibernate/validator/cfg/ConstraintMapping;**

I have searched online but can't find anything.  Also, Hibernate Validator's documentation site is down.  I did use Java Decompiler and I see this:

```
public abstract interface HibernateValidatorConfiguration
  extends Configuration<HibernateValidatorConfiguration>
{
  public static final String FAIL_FAST = "hibernate.validator.fail_fast";
  public static final String VALIDATED_VALUE_HANDLERS = "hibernate.validator.validated_value_handlers";
  public static final String CONSTRAINT_DEFINITION_CONTRIBUTORS = "hibernate.validator.constraint_definition_contributors";
  public static final String CONSTRAINT_MAPPING_CONTRIBUTOR = "hibernate.validator.constraint_mapping_contributor";
  public static final String TIME_PROVIDER = "hibernate.validator.time_provider";

  public abstract ResourceBundleLocator getDefaultResourceBundleLocator();

  public abstract ConstraintMapping createConstraintMapping();

  public abstract HibernateValidatorConfiguration addMapping(ConstraintMapping paramConstraintMapping);

  public abstract HibernateValidatorConfiguration failFast(boolean paramBoolean);

  public abstract HibernateValidatorConfiguration addValidatedValueHandler(ValidatedValueUnwrapper<?> paramValidatedValueUnwrapper);

  public abstract ConstraintDefinitionContributor getDefaultConstraintDefinitionContributor();

  public abstract HibernateValidatorConfiguration addConstraintDefinitionContributor(ConstraintDefinitionContributor paramConstraintDefinitionContributor);

  public abstract HibernateValidatorConfiguration externalClassLoader(ClassLoader paramClassLoader);

  public abstract HibernateValidatorConfiguration timeProvider(TimeProvider paramTimeProvider);
}

public abstract interface ConstraintMapping
{
  public abstract <C> TypeConstraintMappingContext<C> type(Class<C> paramClass);
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Did you run mvn:dependency-tree for your project and only HV 5.2 was shown there? Maybe Hadoop itself comes with HV 4.x? [The docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/) are up again btw., sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: I ran that and don't see 4.2.0Final as a dependency.  I'll have to check whether Hadoop has HV 4.x.  Thanks for getting the documentation back online!  :)